# Create an XMPP/Jabber server in C# using only the libraries/services available in .NET

Tags: c#, xmpp, instant-messaging

How can I make a customised [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)/[Jabber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) server in C# using *only* the libraries/services in .NET?

Is it possible? I've been searching the Internet for the last hour looking for an answer and all I can see is 'agsXMPP'.

Comment: Of course it is *possible*.  But questions this broad are off-topic on SO.  We can't really explain to you every detail of implementing an XMPP server in a single SO answer.  That would take pages and pages.

Comment: Do you know any sites that has a tutorial for my problem? thanks!

Comment: On writing an entire XMPP server from scratch?  No... I don't think anyone has written a tutorial on that topic...

Comment: I see. How/Where do you think I should start? :( thanks!

Comment: Probably with the [XMPP specs](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/) or a decent XMPP book.

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do an xmpp server using libraries. Basically, using sockets to handle bytes and use StreamParser on Matrix or AgsXMPP to handle streamstart (stream:stream), elements (iq, auth, session, bind, starttls), etc...

Matrix.vNext (renamed to XmppDotNet): **Freeware(?)** (multiplatform support, built using dotnetty and reactive design you can design own server) https://www.ag-software.net/matrix-vnext/
AgsXMPP: **Free** (not stable, no .netstandard support)

Example: [csharp/Server - GitLab](https://gitlab.com/matrix-xmpp/samples/tree/master/csharp/Server) See: XmppServerConnection.cs